# Pygame clock and event loops

Tags: python, loops, pygame

i am new to pygame and i was wondering what an event loop is and what clock does in this situation, like what is `clock.tick(60)`? I don't understand any explanations online

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time.
That meas that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

[`for event in pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) handles the internal events an retrieves a list of external events (the events are removed from the internal event queue).
If you press the close button of the window, than the causes the `QUIT` event and you'll get the event by `for event in pygame.event.get()`. See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) for the different event types. e.g. `KEYDOWN` occurs once when a key is pressed.

e.g. The following loop prints the names of the a key once it it pressed:

```py
run = True
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```