# Arrow Key Movement in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am starting with pygame and can't seem to figure out how to implement continuous movement. This is my current code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode(((500, 500)))
pygame.display.set_caption(("First Game"))

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 10

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (200, 23, 255), (350, 350, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
   
pygame.quit()
```

As I have just started, I can't think of any possible solutions. Would be really nice of you if you can resolve this issue of mine. I know there is going to be some really stupid bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the rectangle `x`, `y` instead of constant `350, 350`:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(window, (200, 23, 255), (350, 350, width, height))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(window, (200, 23, 255), (x, y, width, height))
```

---

For a smooth movement you need to set `vel` to 1 and decrease the delay in the application loop.
Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode(((500, 500)))
pygame.display.set_caption(("First Game"))

x, y = 50, 50
width, height = 40, 60
vel = 1

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (200, 23, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
   
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but any idea how to make the movement smoother as its really laggy

Comment: @AnayGarodia Change `vel = 10` and  `pygame.time.delay(100)` or use `pygame.time.Clock`. See [Pygame clock and event loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444161/pygame-clock-and-event-loops/60447013#60447013)

Comment: @AnayGarodia I've extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Draw your rectangle at `x` and `y` coordinates as origin.

Comment: that's not really what he is asking for, he is asking for continuous movement. Try to read another time the question before answering it wrongly.

Comment: @ƒkS124 If the player were drawn at x, y it would be a continuous move.

Comment: Thought he were asking for a way to press the key and get a fluid movement, but obviously I understood wrongly, my bad sorry.

Comment: @ƒkS124 *"Thought he were asking for a way to press the key and get a fluid movement, [...]"* - Yes he did. However `pygame.key.get_pressed()` does what he want. See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down)

Answer (score 0):

For each key press, add the following code `x_vel += vel` or `y_vel += vel`. Then use

```
x += x_vel
y += y_vel

x_vel *= .9
y_vel *= .9
```

And then adjust the values accordingly. You could porobably make a variable called `friction` that holds the value that you multiply `x_vel` and `y_vel` by.