# Is there a way to call the only important arguments of a sprite class?

Tags: python, pygame

So I recently made a game in python where the player collects green dots. It's unfinished, I'll implement more into the game later.

But I have a problem. I want my sprite to move using the arrow keys, change the position of X and Y depending on which key is used and ignore the rest. But it gives me an error saying that I am missing other arguments. Is there a way around this?

Code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, posX, posY, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [posX, posY]
        self.eat = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/Apple_Bite-Simon_Craggs-1683647397.mp3")

    def __call__(self, posX, posY):
        self.rect.center = [posX, posY]


class Target(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, posX, posY, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [posX, posY]
        self.eat = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/Apple_Bite-Simon_Craggs-1683647397.mp3")

    def eat(self):
        self.eat.play()
        pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, target_group, True)


pygame.init()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

player = Player(50, 50, 300, 250, (0, 255, 127))
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)
player_group.update()

target_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for target in range(6):
    target_sprite = Target(25, 25, random.randrange(15, screen_width), random.randrange(15, screen_height),
                           (127, 255, 0))
    target_group.add(target_sprite)


run = True
while run:
    screen.fill((0, 16, 16))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change_pos = Player(posX=-0, posY=+0.4)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change_pos = Player(posX=-0, posY=-0.4)

    player_group.draw(screen)
    player_group.update()
    target_group.draw(screen)
    target_group.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

It gives me this error FYI:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'width', 'height', and 'color'
```

Plus I am new, anyways thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call operator has to be performed on the instance object (`player`) rather than on the class (`Player`):

<s>`Player(posX=-0, posY=+0.4)`</s>

```py
player(posX=-0, posY=+0.4)
```

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.center`) of the rectangle:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, posX, posY, color):
        super().__init__()
        # [...]

        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.rect.center = round(self.x), round(self.y)

    def __call__(self, posX, posY):
        self.x += posX
        self.y += posY
        self.rect.center = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```

See also [Pygame doesn't let me use float for rect.move, but I need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468413/pygame-doesnt-let-me-use-float-for-rect-move-but-i-need-it/63468637#63468637).

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

If you want to achieve a continuously movement, you have to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player(posX=-0, posY=+0.4)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player(posX=-0, posY=-0.4)
```

See also [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down) and [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame/64494842#64494842)

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed. The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

```py
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    clock .tick(100)
  
    # [...]
```

See also [Pygame clock and event loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444161/pygame-clock-and-event-loops/60447013#60447013).

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import sys
import random


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, posX, posY, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.rect.center = round(self.x), round(self.y)
        self.eat = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/Apple_Bite-Simon_Craggs-1683647397.mp3")

    def __call__(self, posX, posY):
        self.x += posX
        self.y += posY
        self.rect.center = round(self.x), round(self.y)

class Target(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, posX, posY, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [posX, posY]
        self.eat = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/Apple_Bite-Simon_Craggs-1683647397.mp3")

    def eat(self):
        self.eat.play()
        pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, target_group, True)


pygame.init()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

player = Player(50, 50, 300, 250, (0, 255, 127))
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)
player_group.update()

target_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for target in range(6):
    target_sprite = Target(25, 25, random.randrange(15, screen_width), random.randrange(15, screen_height),
                           (127, 255, 0))
    target_group.add(target_sprite)


run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    clock .tick(100)
    screen.fill((0, 16, 16))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player(posX=-0, posY=+1)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player(posX=-0, posY=-1)

    player_group.draw(screen)
    player_group.update()
    target_group.draw(screen)
    target_group.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.

Comment: The arrows are working as expected but I cant seem to get the WASD to work this time. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: @colappse e.g. for "d": `if keys[pygame.K_d]:` for "down" or "d": `if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or  keys[pygame.K_d]:`